# Page reload is not asking for form resubmit

Tags: javascript, html, form-submit, reload, ruby-on-rails-6

I have my application running Ruby on Rails 6. Like any other application, I have some forms too. When I submit the form with any error, the URL gets replaced with form action and now when I reload the page I get route error -
**No route matches [GET] "/admins/password"**
Usually when we reload page after form submit with errors, The browser asks if we want to resubmit the form. But in my case this is not happening. This is a basic stuff but no idea what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I found really helpful regarding my question.
https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/60

Answer (score 0):

try to insert `event.preventDefault()` on your `onsubmit` event handler function. If you post some code would be helpful.

Easy code would be:

```
document.querySelector("#myform").onsubmit = function(event){

 // ...check for errors

  if(errors){
     event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Comment: Doing this would not even allow my form to submit?

Comment: you can verify if there's errors and return false or do the `event.preventDefault()` as I said. If there are no errors, you can proceed with the form submission. I just edited my response. I hope it helps.